# How to prove that this set is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Lets say $a_1, a_n$ are normed vectors.

Why is the set $C = \{\Sigma_{i=1}^n \lambda_ia_i: \lambda_i \ge0\}$ closed? The $\lambda$'s can be any non-negative numbers. So C is the set of all non-negative linear combinations of the n vectors.

I tried both the method with open balls, and the method with a converging sequence(show that the point the series is convergin to is in C), but still I do not see why. (PS: If it is untrue in the generalized version, you can assume that the vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Comment: Are we working in a finite dimensional space?

Comment: @DanZimm Yes, the original theorem was in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so if that makes it easier, then assume that.

Comment: The general case reduces to the finite dimensional case, since finite dimensional subspaces are closed.

Comment: @NateEldredge But how is C a subspace? A subspace must be closed under scalar-multiplication, if you multiply a vector in C with -1, it may not be in C?

Comment: I'm not claiming that $C$ is a subspace.  But let $V$ be our ambient normed space, and $W$ the linear span of $C$.  Then $W$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$, hence closed.  If we can show $C$ is closed in $W$, it follows that $C$ is closed in $V$.

Comment: Here is a hint: if we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ is a basis, any vector $x$ can be written uniquely as $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(x) e_i$.  Show that $x \mapsto \lambda_i(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hello, I understand that if we show that C is closed in W then C is closed in V. And I think by choosing $\delta=\epsilon$ we see that the function is continuous? But I don't see how this makes C closed in W?

Comment: I know that every vector in W is a linear combination of the original a-vectors. And if the original a-vectors where ortogonal, then I see that your hint would work. Because then if we have a convergent sequence in C then we also have a convergent sequence in W, and it converges to a vector z in w. If that vector was not in C, then it must be a linear combination of the a-vectors where at least one $\lambda$ is negative, and then we could take an epsilon ball around that lambda(continuity of your function), and show that the sequence could in fact not converge to z, but the a-vectors may not

Comment: be orthogonal?, so how do I solve that?